# A few questions about a specific ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra, projective-module

My question is kinda long, so please bear with me... And  I only need hints to get me started.

So, I'm working on the ring  $R  =\left(  \begin{matrix} \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Q}  \\ 0 & \mathbb{Q}   \end{matrix} \right)$ .

$\textbf{1.}$  I  consider the left ideal $I_1= \left(  \begin{matrix} 0& \mathbb{Q}  \\ 0 & 0   \end{matrix} \right)$ ; I am trying to show that it is not projective, any help with that ?

$\textbf{2.} $    I also  wanna show that if $M$ is a projective right $R$-module then any submodule of $M$ is also projective. I also need a nudge in the right direction to prove this claim.

Thanks

Comment: For 2 it's sufficient to see that any right ideal of $R$ is projective.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! May you elaborate as to why that is sufficient?

Comment: It's a well known theorem: a ring is right hereditary if and only if every right ideal is projective, exercise 18.10 in Anderson-Fuller.

Comment: @egreg Thank you!!! As for 1, is it enough if I show that $I$ is not a direct summand of $R$; and hence not projective?

Comment: No, that's not sufficient. A direct summand of $R$ is projective, but the converse is, in general, false.

Comment: @egreg ok so I know that  $R$ has three right ideals $\left(  \begin{matrix} 0& \mathbb{Q}  \\ 0 & 0   \end{matrix} \right)$, $\left(  \begin{matrix} 0& \mathbb{Q}  \\ 0 & \mathbb{Q}   \end{matrix} \right)$ and $\left(  \begin{matrix} \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Q}  \\ 0 & 0   \end{matrix} \right)$. I tried to prove that they're projective using liftings, to no avail. So maybe each is a  direct summand of $R$. could you help me show that?

Comment: If all right ideals are summands, the ring would be semisimple.

Comment: @Mia Those are three right ideals but I hope you don't think that is all of them. The ring is not right Artinian, and it has infinitely descending chains of right ideals.

Answer (score 0):

*getting this out of unanswered-limbo*

---

Expanding on the comments, the condition that all submodules of projective right modules being projective is equivalent to all right ideals being projective. The following comes from : Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* p 46+47.

Following the classification of right ideals, they come in three flavors:

$$M_1=\begin{bmatrix}n\mathbb Z & \mathbb Q \\ 0 & \mathbb Q\end{bmatrix} \text {with } n\neq 0$$
$$M_2=\begin{bmatrix}n\mathbb Z & \mathbb Q \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \text {with } n\neq 0$$
$$M_V=\begin{bmatrix}0&p \\ 0&q\end{bmatrix} \text{ where } (p,q)\in V$$ for some fixed subspace $V$ of $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$.

To show that $\begin{bmatrix}0&\mathbb Q \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is not a projective left $R$ module, he gives an argument that its projectivity implies $\mathbb Q$ is projective as a $\mathbb Z$ module, which it isn't.   All this takes a bit of detail that doesn't make for a great post, so I'll direct you to the source itself for details.